# Choose one number from $\{1, \ldots, 1000\}$ randomly. What is the probability that the chosen number is a square of an integer? a cube of an integer?

Tags: probability

Choose one number from $\{1, \ldots, 1000\}$ randomly. What is the probability that the chosen number is:

a) divisible by $7$

b) a square of an integer?

c) a cube of an integer?

My answer for a is $1000/7=142$, so $142/1000$. The probability is $0.142$.  But for b or c, I don't have any idea.

Comment: Just count the squares in [1,1000] which are in bijective correspondence with the numbers from $1$ to $31$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer.

a)(1000/7)/1000=0.142

b) $31<\sqrt{1000}<32$, 31/1000=0.031.

c) $\sqrt[3]{1000}=10$,  10/1000=0.01.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: answer for a cannot be >1!
Your answer is (1000/7)/7 which is 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

Just find out how many squares/cubes of integers are present among these numbers.

Provided that the outcomes are equiprobable we have the rule:

$$\text{probability = number of favourable outcomes divided by number of possible outcomes.}$$

Actually you already applied that rule yourself in a) contradicting that you don't have any idea.